# Capture a curl response in Scala variable

Tags: scala, curl

I am trying to get the `cURL` response in a variable. I am getting the response on the console but not able to save it in a variable.

```
val cmd = Seq("curl", "--silent", "-ki", s"$hostName")
val returnVal = cmd.!
println("CURL Response: " + returnVal.toString)
```

**Output**:

`CURL Response: 0`

Would be great if anyone could help me with the issue.

Comment: Why would you use cURL in a Scala app/lib rather than one WS lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs with a command-line interface (CLI) communicate their results via 3 channels:

1. the exit code (an `Int` value)
2. text sent to STDOUT
3. text sent to STDERR

The ProcessBuilder `.!` method captures the exit code. The `.!!` method captures the STDOUT `String`. In order to capture all 3 channels you'll need to use a `ProcessLogger`.

Consult the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html).